# Soft Keyboard comes over the EditText

Tags: android, textbox, keyboard, titanium

I am using Appcelerator's Titanium to develop an Android application. When focus comes over one of the EditText(at lower end of page) the keypad covers the EditText so when I am keying text, I can't see what's being keyed in. What are my options ?

1. How to move EditText higher on the screen ?
2. Some applications show "model" form behavior where just that EditText & keyboard shows, any examples of how to do this?

Comment: Post your code and layout.  Also I think you mean `EditText`.

Comment: guess my question is silly, but how do u set edittext on titanium?

Comment: any luck? Can you please share the solution ?

Answer (score 21):

Ensure that you have specified the `Window Adjustment Mode` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for the `Activity`in which you want to control the `SoftKeyboard`

Like this:

```
<activity name="YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
</activity>
```

or

```
<activity name="YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan">
</activity>
```

Refer this : [Enabling resize mode and other window features](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my case after struggling came to know that it is depends on your layout alignment

If you are showing the full screen with out status bar ...

The property .. adjust pan or adjust resize won't work to move the edit text up when keyboard showing.. the entire layout including above the views of edit text also moves up

-- the solution is I have removed the option to show the full screen in manifest file and used 
windows soft input to 'resize' in the manifest file.

Thanks
Vinod Sakala

Answer (score -2):

At creation time of a *window*, add the `windowSoftInputMode` property.

```
var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    // ...
    // add here your other window properties
    // ...
    windowSoftInputMode: Ti.UI.Android.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN
});
```

see [Titanium API](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-windowSoftInputMode)