# EditText in ListView header in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a custom view in ListView's header, this custom view contains a set of EditTexts for user input. Then the ListView's body contains a list of products.

My Problem is:
When the user taps on the EditText, the Keyboard moves up, and the EditText field is pushed up off the screen.

is there any way to move the EditText field right on top of the keyboard? or within the shown screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be addressed with a setting in the `Manifest.xml` file. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907116/soft-keyboard-comes-over-the-edittext) for details.

Comment: For me same case but the EditText is not gaining any focus.keyboard is not showing please suggest on this.